# How to stop a functionapp in a slot using azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I would like to issue a command using Azure CLI that stops a functions app in a particular deployment slot only.

The Azure CLI 2.0 documentation [Azure CLI 2.0 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_functionapp_stop) lists the command:

```
az functionapp stop --name
                    --resource-group
```

But it is not clear to me how to stop not the "main" app, but the app in a particular deployment slot.

In my case the slot is called dev and the app is called myapp.  I've tried:

```
az functionapp stop --name=dev --resource-group=myresourcegroup
The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/dev' under resource group myresourcegroup' was not found.

az functionapp stop --name=myapp/dev --resource-group=myresourcegroup
az functionapp stop --name='myapp/dev' --resource-group=myresourcegroup
Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/long-guid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myapp%2Fdev/start?api-version=2016-08-01
```

I'm able to stop the main app no problem.  And when I issue the command to stop the main app, the app in the deployment slot does not stop (as I can see by checking in the portal GUI).

So, how can I stop the app in the deployment slot from the command line?

Comment: I think it's not supported yet, there is [a github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/227)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `az resource invoke-action --action stop --ids` to stop funtion app slot

For example:

```
az resource invoke-action --action stop --ids  /subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/shuiResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuiFunctionApp/slots/shuiSlot
```

Answer (score 1):

`az functionapp stop --name MyFunctionApp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --slot yourslotname`

This has been added since the question and the accepted answer.

[Reference Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-stop)